# c# What is the different between static class and non-static (I am talking about the class itself not the field)

Tags: c#, class, static

The syntax maybe wrong

```
public static class Storage
{
    public static string filePath { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class Storage
{
    private void Storage () {};
    public static string filePath { get; set; }
}
```

I got this from an example on the internet.
what is the use of the second one?

Comment: @Tuzo - Related not duplicate.. That question is a comparison

Comment: @OP - I think your 2nd code snippet should be private void Storage() {}; ... as in private ctor

Comment: @Gishu Sorry. You are right :) but still every know it, editing it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at the IL code, the static class will be `abstract` and `sealed` which gives two important qualities:

- You cannot create instances from it
- It cannot be inherited

A consequence of the first point is that a static class cannot contain non-static members. There may be many uses of static members in a non-static class. One common use is to have a class factory:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }

    public static SomeClass Create(int defaultValue)
    {
        SomeClass result = new SomeClass();
        result.SomeInt = defaultValue;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eh? Your example is not a static class?

Comment: That isn't a static class though?

Comment: @Thorarin and @Svish: that is correct. It is serving to answer the last question of the use of static members in non-static types (as I interpreted the past question in the original post)

Answer (score 6):

Here is the official/MSDN hot-spot to learn about [static classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> The main features of a static class
>   are:
>   * They only contain static members.
>   * They cannot be instantiated.
>   * They are sealed.
>   * They cannot contain Instance Constructors

Basically a static class is identical to a 'normal'/non-static class which has only static methods and a private ctor. Marking it as static helps clarify intent and helps the compiler do some compile-time checks to disallow certain things e.g. disallow instantiation.

Real-world uses I can think of: Use it to house or as a way to organize

- utility methods (methods not associated with any instance of a type) e.g. Math for Min and Max methods
- extension methods e.g. StopWatchExtensions for a Reset method on a StopWatch

Answer (score 3):

Lots of classes have both instance and static methods. String for example has:

```
String.Format(string, arg0, arg1, arg2) // static method
```

And

```
String myString = "    Hello world!";
myString = myString.Substring(4);       // instance method
```

If you're asking why both the class and the method need the static keyword it's simply by design. I see what you're asking, if the class is static then of course all the methods are static as well, seems kind of redundant to put it there twice. I don't know if there's a good reason for that or not.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a class as **static**:

- It is allowed to have **only static members**,
- It **cannot be instantiated** (it has no public constructor), and
- It **cannot be inherited** (it's sealed).

Any class which is not declared as static can be instantiated, inherited, and can have non-static members.

Answer (score 3):

Static classes are only available from C#2 upwards. In C#1 you would have to seal your class and specify that it is not instantiable by added a private constructor to get this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

A static class is basically the same as a non-static class, but there is one difference: a static class cannot be instantiated. In other words, you cannot use the new keyword to create a variable of the class type. Because there is no instance variable, you access the members of a static class by using the class name itself.

```
public static class Storage
{
   public static string filePath { get; set; }
}
```

in this,the class need not to be instantiate.so same with the filepath ,it will occupy unique value of class Storage for all object.

```
public class Storage
{
    private void Storage {};
    public static string filePath { get; set; }
}
```

in this,the class is non static,need to be instantiate

Answer (score 0):

As we know variables and functions are of two types-instance and class.

A static class -has only class variables no instance variables.

Hence cannot be instantiated,only accessible by Classname.method().

It contains only Private constructors no public constructor is there.

A static class contains only static members.