# Object reference is required for non-static TextBox

Tags: c#, windows

C# n00b here. I can't figure out why I get the error on `TextBox.text` saying:

[image]

On googling the error, it seems like it's to do with my TextBox being static..? I can you please explain what this all means? How do I make it non-static? I have a good background in Java, Obj-C, Python and Swift if you can draw any similarities from there.

**Code:**

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create OpenFileDialog 
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();



            // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            dlg.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.text";


            // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();


            // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
            if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
            {
                // Open document 
                string filename = dlg.FileName;
                TextBox.Text = filename;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Change the name of your TextBox to 'txtFileName' and then try 'txtFileName.Text = filename;'.  Also, change the name of your function from 'Button' to 'OnButtonClick'

Comment: Saagar Elias Jacky is correct.  "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" is a *class*.  You need to create an *instance* of that class - for example, "txtFileName", or "textBox1".

Comment: `TextBox` and `Button` basically class name, so don't use them as name of your method name or text box name.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a TextBox in your xaml, like this:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="100" Height="50" />
```

you can reference it from the code behind (in your example the `MainWindow` class) by the name like this:

```
textBox1.Text = "Hello World";
```

The class [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a static class. For more info on static class see this post:

[c# What is the different between static class and non-static (I am talking about the class itself not the field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276333/c-sharp-what-is-the-different-between-static-class-and-non-static-i-am-talking)

Answer (score 1):

`Text` is an instance property. So you need to invoke it using an ***instance*** of the `TextBox` class.

When you do:

```
TextBox.Text = filename; // "TextBox" is a class, not an instance.
```

You are trying to invoke `Text` as if it was a static property, but it isn't.

So I don't know if you do have an instance of a `TextBox` somewhere in your window. If you added one to your WPF app, by default in VS2015 it will be called `textBox` (which can easily be confused with `TextBox`). Whatever it's called, you'll want to use *that* to set the `Text` property.  Like this:

```
// consider prefixing with "this" to make sure
// you are using an instance name and not a class name by mistake.
this.textBox.Text = filename;
```

Answer (score 1):

`TextBox` is a control name and I don't think you can use `TextBox.Tex = filename;`

You need to give a name to your `TextBox` control using the `Name` property in XAML and then assign value to the `Text` property in your code behind file.

Something like, name your text box as  `txtFileName` and then try assigning value like `txtFileName.Text = filename;`

Also, giving a name like `Button` to an event will definitely cause exception. You should better use some name like `OnButtonClick` to handle the Button Click event, rather than `private void Button()`.